# Matched-maturity vanilla swap in Quantlib

Tags: quantlib

Firstly apologies if this has been answered elsewhere.

I am using QuantLib (via Excel) to build a "standard" bond pricing sheet: prices, yields, spline AND matched-maturity ASW.

I can price the bonds, and have successfully built a forecast (Euribor) and discount (EONIA) curve. I can use qlMakeVanillaSwap() to define a spot-start swap by tenor (eg "1y","2Y" etc) and it works fine. However I am struggling to define a "broken date" swap, ie one which starts T+2 and ends on a given date (and so usually has a short stub on the first payment), to match the bond maturity. All the examples I can find have integer year tenors.

I would be grateful if someone could point me to the right method (can be in python, C++ or Excel). Or do I have to go down the route of creating explicit fixed and floating rate schedules for the swaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be: Yes, I do have to create explicit fixed and floating rate schedules, using qlSchedule(), but it turns out to be not too onerous. NB. I am pricing a vanilla EUR ABB vs 6m Euribor swap.

As for pricing, it seems the qlMakeVanillaSwap() is doing a few helpful things in one call, but only IF your swap has a whole-period tenor (eg "1y"). I found the answer for what I wanted to do in the example sheet that came with the QuantLibXL download package.

[image]

The other thing that qlMakeVanillaSwap() is doing (in addition to creating the schedules) is setting the Pricing Engine (which is used to discount the cashflows). In the longer version you have to (a) set it yourself using qlInstrumentSetPricingEngine() and (b) pass the result of that call to the Trigger parameter of qlVanillaSwapFairRate(), to establish the calculation order.